# Data type for a HTML Page in JAVA

Tags: java, html, types

Which data type should be used to store an HTML page in JAVA?

Comment: I would say it depends on what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: where u want to store JAVA page? In database or in file?

Comment: what do you mean by storing HTML page ? maybe the form data (stuff a user filled the form with) or the hole HTML source of the page ??

Comment: If you want to store entire html source code, you can use String but you need to escape those special html characters before storing

Comment: Try to parse HTML like XML page. You can store as a b-tree.

Answer (score 1):

*Recommendation:* Store the page in a [**(Jsoup) Document**](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html).

**pros:**

- you can **parse** those documents from string / file / website in a single line
- all entities are **escaped** (and can be **unescaped**)
- **pretty printing**
- you get a **string out of** it with a single line of code - a html string as well as a *text only* one
- you can easily **select** / **modify** your html
- html is "**cleaned**"
- ...

see: http://jsoup.org/

But some more informations about what you want to do would be helpful ...

Comment: Thannks a lot.. the recommendation worked perfectly.I wanted to store and do operations on an html page in java

Comment: If this solved your problem, please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you will do with it, I'd suggest a

```
java.lang.String
```

because that's what it actually is. A character string.